# Invalid token and bracket expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, syntax

I'm trying to create a service which can read and add entries to a MongoDB database. I've got the reading part working, but when I try to add the method (if that's what it's called) that adds entries, I get some errors in my code. I'm extremely new and can't see the errors, so I'd appreciate any help to understand why it's wrong

```
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using project.Model;

namespace project.Services
{
    public class UsersService
    {
        private readonly IMongoCollection<User> _users;
        public UsersService(UserDatabaseSettings settings)
        {
            var client = new MongoClient(settings.ConnectionString);
            var database = client.GetDatabase(settings.DatabaseName);
            _users = database.GetCollection<User>(settings.UsersCollectionName);
        }
        public List<User> Get()
        {
            return _users.Find(user => true).ToList();
        }
        public User Get(string id)
        {
            return _users.Find<User>(user => user.Id ==
            id).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        public User Create(User user)
        {
        _users.InsertOne(user);
        return user;
        }
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
Invalid token 'return' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration [project],

Invalid token '' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration [project],

} expected [project, project]
```

I'm pretty sure there are enough brackets so I don't know why it's expecting a '}'. Any help appreciated

Comment: On which lines are the three errors reported?

Comment: Well this was weird, I restarted my workstation and the error actually isn't there any more. Thanks for your attention though!